# Perl UDP Server: How to retrieve client socket?

Tags: perl, sockets, udp

It is easy to get the client socket using a TCP server:

```
$new_sock = $sock->accept();
```

However with a UDP server there seems no way to retrieve the client socket so I can refer to it later.

```
Client_A->UDPServer (store client socket)
Client_B->UDPServer
Client_B<-UDPServer
Clinet_A<-UDPServer (retrieve client socket)
```

Comment: UDP does not know of a connection, so there is no `accept` call there.

Comment: You need to use `recv` and `send` with the socket addresses. Example in the documentation: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#UDP%3a-Message-Passing

Comment: yes that solved it!

Comment: Re "*UDP does not know of a connection*", True, but you can still call `connect` to set the default address for `send`, effectively making it look like there's a concept of connection if you only want to talk to one peer. In the OP's case, the clients could use this trick, but not the server.

Answer (score 1):

1) Save each client from which a datagram was received:

```
push @client, $sock->peername;
```

2) At some point send them an answer - all at once:

```
for my $client( @client) {
    #send SOCKET,MSG,FLAGS,**TO**
    send($sock, "Hey\n", 0, $client);
    #                       ^^^^^^^ 4.Parameter: TO
}
```